# PHP: Contact form sending e-Mail even when forms not filled?

Tags: php, html, email, contacts, contact-form

I've been working on websites for a while now and I keep running into this issue with my contact forms.

So I make sure that I include the "required" on contact forms, and if the form isn't filled out, it's great. It makes sure that the user puts information into the fields for the information to be sent.

However, on iOS that is not the case. Those required tags get ignored, so I constructed my PHP to ensure that the inputs were still required.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Here is the HTML contact form:

```
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="phoneInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What phone number can we reach you at? (Optional)" /><br />

        <input type="email" name="email" class="emailInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What is your primary e-mail address?" required /><br />

        <textarea name="message" id="message" autocomplete="off" placeholder="How may we assist you?" required></textarea><br />

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" id="button"/>
            <div class="ease"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

updated PHP:

```
<?php

// Name of sender
$name=$_GET["name"];

// Phone number of sender
$number=$_GET["phone"]; 

// Mail of sender
$mail_from=$_GET["email"];

// Message
$message=$_GET["message"];

// Subject 
$subject= "Someone has sent you a message from your contact form!";

// Message Headers
$headers = 'From: ' .$name."\r\n". 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from."\r\n" . 'Callback Number: '.$number."\r\n";

// E-mail to:
$to ='shawn@synergycomposites.net';

// Empty variables, tests to see if any of the fields are empty
$emptyName    = empty($name);
$emptyEmail   = empty($mail_from);
$emptyMessage = empty($message);

// Perform if tests to see if any of the fields are empty, and redirect accordingly
if ($emptyName == true) {
    header ("location:/#modalFailure");
} else {
    if ($emptyEmail == true) {
        header ("location:/#modalFailure");
    } else {
        if ($emptyMessage == true) {
            header ("location:/#modalFailure");
        } else {
            header ("location:/#modalSuccess");
            mail($to, $subject ,$message, $headers);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're sending the email before checking the fields.

Comment: @J08691, that didn't fix anything - moving the $send_contact below the fields. Any idea? Also, is there any way to keep the user on the current page rather than redirecting them to the index page of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling the mail() function before checking the fields. This function actually sends the email. The return variable $send_contact is just a Boolean whether the function succeeded or not. Something like this should work:

```
if(empty($name) || empty($mail_from) || empty($message)) {
  header('location:/#modalFailure');
} else {
  $mail_sent = mail($to, $subject ,$message, $headers);
  if(!$mail_sent) {
    header("location:/#modalFailure");
  } else {
    header("location:/#modalSuccess");
  }
}
```

This code will run into issues if the form submits non-empty strings. For instance this `"  "` instead of `""` or `NULL`. It would also be advisable to add [filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) and [validation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) to this code.

( on another note you may want to use $_POST instead of $_GET for form submissions.)

Comment: Ah, so just drop that below the if statements?

Edit: I'll give the $_POST a shot!

Comment: that didn't do me any good. It's doing the same thing for some reason.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know if it works for me. I've wanted to add validation, but I'm not exactly sure how it works. Any links you could send me to that may have some good advice? Thanks!